# BETWEEN operation in BigQuery givies no results

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find a shorter way of executing the below command in Bigquery.

```
select * from `taxirides.historical_taxi_rides_raw` 
where pickup_latitude <=90 and pickup_latitude >= -90
and dropoff_latitude <=90 and  dropoff_latitude >=-90
and pickup_longitude <=180 and  pickup_longitude >= -80
and dropoff_longitude <=180 and dropoff_longitude >= -80
limit 100
```

I tried BETWEEN operation (shown below). However it returned no results (and no error either). I do not understand why.

```
select * from `taxirides.historical_taxi_rides_raw` 
where pickup_latitude BETWEEN 90 and -90
and dropoff_latitude BETWEEN 90 and -90
and pickup_longitude BETWEEN -180 and 80
and dropoff_longitude BETWEEN -180 and 80
```

The data is taken from Bigquery sample dataset.

[image: The data/columns used for the above query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below (note change in the order for first two `between`s)

```
select * from `taxirides.historical_taxi_rides_raw` 
where pickup_latitude BETWEEN -90 and 90
and dropoff_latitude BETWEEN -90 and 90
and pickup_longitude BETWEEN -180 and 80
and dropoff_longitude BETWEEN -180 and 80
```

Answer (score 0):

As i am not sure which data type you have for fields but you should do two modifications :-

1. With BETWEEN function you should give first smaller (lesser) value then bigger(larger) value. You have given opposite values for 2 fields `pickup_latitude & dropoff_latitude` : I have corrected in bellow give query.
2. Try to use cast to change data type of fields, if your input fields are string.

Your modified query is:-

```sql
WITH `taxirides.historical_taxi_rides_raw` AS (
SELECT '-73.9' as pickup_latitude , '40.7' AS dropoff_latitude , '73.9' AS pickup_longitude , '40.7' AS dropoff_longitude 

)
select * from `taxirides.historical_taxi_rides_raw` 
where cast(pickup_latitude as float64) BETWEEN -90 and 90
and cast(dropoff_latitude as float64) BETWEEN -90 and 90
and cast(pickup_longitude as float64) BETWEEN -180 and 80
and cast(dropoff_longitude as float64) BETWEEN -180 and 80
```